# Extending a consistent set of sentences to a complete, witnessing, consistent set of sentences

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation, set-theory

I'm attempting to unpack the following paragraph from a proof of the Model Existence Theorem (p.44 on [this set of notes](https://dec41.user.srcf.net/notes/II_L/logic_and_set_theory.pdf)):

> Suppose we have a consistent $S$ in the language $L = L(Ω, Π)$. Extend $S$ to a consistent $S_1$ such that $p ∈ S_1$ or $(¬p) ∈ S$ for each sentence $p ∈ L$ (by applying Zorn’s lemma to get a maximal consistent $S_1$). In particular, $S_1$ is complete, meaning $S_1 ⊢ p$ or $S_1 ⊢ ¬p$ for all $p$. Then for each sentence of the form $(∃x)p$ in $S_1$, add a new constant $c$ to $L$ and add $p[c/x]$ to $S_1$ — obtaining $T_1$ in language $L_1 = L(Ω ∪ C1, Π)$. It is easy to check that $T_1$ is consistent.
> Extend $T_1$ to a complete theory $S_2 ⊆ L_1$, and add witnesses to form $T_2 ⊆ L_2 = L(Ω ∪ C1 ∪ C2, Π)$. Continue inductively.
> Let $\overline{S} = S_1 ∪ S_2 ∪ · · ·$ in language $\overline{L} = L_1 ∪ L_2 ∪ · · ·$ (i.e. $\overline{L} = L(Ω ∪ C_1 ∪
> C_2 ∪ · · · , Π))$.

---

Here is what I have so far:

**Definition:** for any set of sentences $S$ in the language $L$, define
$$w(S) := S\cup\bigg\{\phi[c/x] : \exists x\phi\in S\bigg\}$$
in the language $w(L)$ consisting of $L$ with enough constants $c$ added (one such constant $c$ per $\exists x\phi$ statement in $S$ is sufficient). Abbreviate $w(w(S))$ as $w^2(S)$ and so on.

*Proof:* $S$ can be extended to a complete, witnessing, consistent set.

***Step 1:*** $S$ can be extended to a complete, consistent set of sentences $S_1$. We apply **Zorn's Lemma** on

$$X := \{T\subseteq L : T \text{ is consistent and } T\supseteq S\}.$$

We can apply **Zorn's Lemma** to get a maximal element $S_1$ of $X$, as

- $X\neq\emptyset$ as $S\in X$.
- Any chain has an upper bound: let $\{T_i\}_{i\in I}$ be one such chain, and consider $T=\bigcup_{i\in I} T_i$. Certainy $T\supseteq S$, and if $T$ was inconsistent there would be $\{\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n\}\in T$ such that $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n\vdash\bot$. Then some $T_m$ contains all such $\phi_k$, implying $T_m$ is inconsistent, a contradiction.

$S_1$ is complete and consistent:

- Completeness: if $S_1$ was incomplete, we could find $\phi\in L$ independent from $S_1$, so that $S_1\cup\{\phi\}$ is consistent and a member of $X$, contradicting the maximality of $S_1$.
- Consistency: if $S_1$ was inconsistent, there would be $\{\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n\}\in S_1$ such that $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n\vdash\bot$ and ... **[need help]**

***Step 2:*** $S$ can be extended to a consistent, witnessing set of sentences $T_1$.
to $S$, forming the language $L_1$ and set of sentences $T_1$. Simply let
$$L_1 := \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}w^n(L)
\ \ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \ \ 
T_1 := \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}w^n(S).$$

$T_1$ is witnessing and consistent:

- $T_1$ is witnessing: if $\exists x\phi$ is in $T_1$, then $\phi[c/x]$ was also added to $T_1$ by definition.
- $T_1$ is consistent: we use induction. The base case is clear, so suppose the result holds up to $N$, but not up to $N+1$ i.e. there would be $\{\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n\}\in T_{N+1}$ such that $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n\vdash\bot$. By consistency of $_N$, some of the $\phi_i$ is of the form $\phi[c/x]$ for some $\exists x\phi$ already in $T_N$ and ... **[need help]**

***Step 3:*** apply ***Step 1*** and ***Step 2*** alternatingly ad infinitum (I currenly do not need help with this).

---

1. How can the consistency steps above be proven?
2. Is the rest of the proof correct?

Comment: In your quote the proof appears as a single paragraph, but there are in fact *four* paragraphs there, each corresponding to a step in the proof: and you are certainly not following (unpacking) those steps as presented.